accessing foreignkey created by database in mvc
How would I access a field from mvc c# controller. I created database using add-migration and update-database. hare is my classes
Members                                                 Membersdetail
public Guid Id                                          public Guid id
name                                                    amount
address                                                 datepaid
sage
public ICollection
{ get;} = new List();
The database created a foreignkey MembersId. I am ok with it but how would i call or access it from controller. thanks
I had tried to define my foreign key from the Memberdetail but it's like a duplicate. Something like this MembersId and MembersId1
